# In Spring Security, after entering correct username and password, it redirects to the home page but it still displays "HTTP 403 Forbidden"

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, spring-security

So I was practicing my SpringBoot+SpringSecurity skill.
In the security configuration:

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configuration(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(Registry -> Registry
                .requestMatchers(Constants.PUBLIC_URL)// /auth/**
                .permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(Constants.AUTHENTICATE_URL)// /api/**
                .hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.USER.name())
        );

        http.sessionManagement(session
                -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        return http.build();
    }
```

This is my authenticate controller:

```
@PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public String processAuthenticate(@Valid @ModelAttribute(name = "user") AuthenticateRequest authenticateRequest, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        bindingResult = authServices.authenticate(authenticateRequest, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "authenticate";
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authenticateRequest.getUsername(),
                        authenticateRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );
        return "redirect:/api/home";
    }
```

So, that's exactly what I think:
if `authServices.authenticate(authenticateRequest, bindingResult);` does not throw any exception, which means the correct username and password are entered!
Next, the SecurityContextHolder will set the Authentication(UsernamePasswordAuthentication) and fill it with username and password.
Finally, send redirect to the url "/api/home".

There are two roles defined: USER and ADMIN.

```
public enum Role {

    USER(Collections.emptySet()),


    ADMIN(Set.of(ADMIN_READ,
            ADMIN_UPDATE, ADMIN_CREATE, ADMIN_DELETE
    ));


    @Getter
    private final Set<Permission> permissions;

    public List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new java.util.ArrayList<>(getPermissions().stream()
                .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission()))
                .toList());
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + this.name()));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

I think it shall be something wrong in the authorities or roles or something. Because when I delete the `.hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.USER.name())` and change it to `permitAll()`

Additionally, there is no AccessDeniedException threw out, only Http 403 Error on the web page.

This is my Mysql table:
'1', 'user1', '$2a$10$faQJhWWffJlvWbN4YDC4tep4TIMDzH3Hze4tH9MMmt6r9NKp49FCe', 'user1@qq.com', 'ADMIN'

'5', 'user2', '$2a$10$qAZAuvoG.aaEMljYfQirZOhjEUsUZ3edcum/Mhc6UPOc.ti0VD7JO', 'user2@qq.com', 'USER'

I've tried:

adding @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")on the homePage controller function but does not help.
and @Secured("ROLE_USER") does not help either.
changing the column "USER" to "ROLE_USER" in the Mysql table does not help.
And, I changed the `.hasAnyRole(Role.ADMIN.name(), Role.USER.name())` to `.hasAuthority("ADMIN")`,to
`.hasAuthority("USER")`,unluckily, they does NOT help.

What I expected:
Just tell me the reason for this annoying problem. I wish I can redirect to the /api/home successfully. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no stored session to keep you logged in once you are redirected. That's what `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS` means: don't create a server-side session, treat every request individually. You have to authenticate somehow when the browser redirects to `/api/home`. There are many options but it boils down to one of the following:

- Enable backend sessions, this will tell Spring to link your requests together via the `JSESSIONID` cookie. This is the simple answer but will lead to problems down the road if you are building an API (see: [REST](https://restfulapi.net/))
- Include authentication token with each request. For example, make an endpoint that accepts a username and password and returns a token (see: [JWT](https://jwt.io/)) to the client (browser). The client would then provide that token as a header on subsequent requests to authenticate.

Comment: should be noted that if selecting JWTs you can not logout the user and that your application will be susceptible to token stealing attacks through cross site scripting etc.